# vs2013 task runner explorer does not detect gruntjs tasks

Tags: visual-studio-2013, gruntjs

Here is a snippet from my gruntjs file in a vs2013 web project. What I am seeing is adding the last line in the initconfig to load the settings stops showing the tasks in the VS2013 Task Runner Explorer. As soon as comment out that line the Task Runner Explorer enumerates my tasks. There are no errors in the output window for the Task Runner ExplorerI .

I can run my gruntfile.js fine using the grunt cli.

```
 grunt.initConfig({

        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        target: grunt.config.get('target'),
        settings: grunt.file.readJSON('config/' + grunt.option('target') + '.json'), //problematic line
karma: {
            unit: {
                configFile: 'karma.conf.js'
            }
        },
```

Comment: did you even find a solution to this problem? It seems like it tries to actually readJSON when refreshing the "Task runner explorer" so you have to have the file there ...

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with grunt.file.readJSON and I solved it by giving my option a self invoked function which checked to see if the file even exists. Something like:

```
settings: function () {
                    if (grunt.file.exists('config/' + grunt.option('target') + '.json')) {
                        return grunt.file.readJSON('config/' + grunt.option('target') + '.json')
                    }
                    return '';
                }()
```